# How to show time since last null value on Grafana

Tags: t-sql, grafana, influxdb

I am using influx DB and grafana to display some data. There are frequently power outages where it will display null data. I want to create a single stat panel that will display the time since the last null value.

When editing the single stat I know about the "Time of last point" and the unit "from now" under options, but I seem to be having trouble with figuring out what the actual query should be to get a time displayed.

Right now my query is:

```
    SELECT ("value") FROM "measurement" 
    WHERE ("host" = 'IP.ADDRESS' AND "and" = 'null') AND $timeFilter 
    GROUP BY time(365d) fill(null)
```

Where value, measurement, and IP.ADDRESS are all filled in with the correct information.

I know what I have is wrong, but I am not sure what to put.

Ideally what I am trying to say in the query is display the last time since the value displayed on grafana was null in the last 365 days.

Comment: Does the `last()` function do what you need? Something like `SELECT last("value") FROM ...`?

Comment: @Jason, that doesn't seem to fix the issue. But I appreciate the response!